# TypeScript - Accessing a variable in a inner object

Tags: javascript, typescript, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I have a type script class which accepts a url (string) as parameter in the constructor. Inside the class, I have a another class which is the view model for a devextreme datagrid. The problem I am facing is I don't know how I can access the url property in a inner object (GridViewModel) which has a function as part of it.

```
export class MyClassOne {
    private myUrl: string;

    constructor(url: string) {
        this.myUrl = url;
    }

    public GridViewModel = {
        dataGridOptions: {
            dataSource : { store: someSource}
                   ...
            aFunction:  function(e){

                // this.myUrl is undefined
                var postUrl =  this.myUrl;               
            }             
        }
    }
}  
var myClassOne = new MyClassOne("https://www.google.com");
```

My question is, how do I access "this.myUrl" in the inner object function? Please help

Thanks,

Comment: You need an instance.

Comment: I don't understand. What "inner class" are you referring to? Are you referring to `GridViewModel`? That's not an "inner class". It's just a property.

Comment: Yes, GridViewModel. I will update the question.

Comment: Anyone know if I am composing badly the question for down voting? I did my research before coming here asking for help

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  There is no "inner class".

Comment: @Slaks, thanks for the feedback, I have updated the question.

Comment: You should correctly indent your code.

Comment: Yep, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scope of **'this'** has changed inside the function.Either u can create an **arrow function** which retains the scope or use a **self variable** to hold the outside scope.

eg of functions with arrow operator. Your function can be replaced as

```
e => {
var postUrl =  this.myUrl;              
}
```

Comment: Hi Franklin, can you please provide an example?

Comment: I think I am getting there

Comment: thanks for the hint, indeed, that's all I needed. Replace function(e) to e=>

Answer (score 0):

So, basically I needed to replace function(e) with e=> to retain the scope of 'this'

```
export class MyClassOne {
    private myUrl: string;

    constructor(url: string) {
        this.myUrl = url;
    }

    public GridViewModel = {
        dataGridOptions: {
            dataSource : { store: someSource}
                   ...
            aFunction:  e => {

                // this.myUrl is undefined
                var postUrl =  this.myUrl;               
            }             
        }
    }
}

var myClassOne = new MyClassOne("https://www.google.com");
```